# Vertices Disappeared

Tags: edit-mode

I've created a UV Sphere and started modifying the vertices via the various editing tools. When I finished editing and went back into Edit mode, I noticed that some of the vertices have disappeared.

As you can see from the image, the center of the sphere appears to have no vertices.

[image]

[image: The center of the bottom sphere is selectable by face]

Can anyone explain in what scenario this would occur?

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: Since it's unclear what editing tools you used, or what your methods were, I can't tell you HOW it happened.... but if you want the points connected again, (with that same face selected), press M (merge), and select "at center".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could triangulate the face, poke it, or merge the vertices together. Also if you want the shape to be rounder, use the loop tools addon to make it a circle.

Comment: Hi. Please add some steps to explain *how* the user should do these steps. Thanks.